# Selection.Insert Error while insert and duplicate cell values

Tags: excel, vba

i need a help, i m trying to insert new rows based on cell value and also need to copy the value to the new row,
Heres the code,

```html
Sub CopyData()
'Updateby Extendoffice 20160922
    Dim xRow As Long
    Dim VInSertNum As Variant
    xRow = 1
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Do While (Cells(xRow, "A") <> "")
        VInSertNum = Cells(xRow, "B")
        If ((VInSertNum > 1) And IsNumeric(VInSertNum)) Then
            ActiveSheet.Unprotect
           Range(Cells(xRow, "A"), Cells(xRow, "B")).Copy
           ActiveSheet.Protect
           Range(Cells(xRow + 1, "A"), Cells(xRow + VInSertNum - 1, "B")).Select
           Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
           xRow = xRow + VInSertNum - 1
        End If
        xRow = xRow + 1
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

I got that code from another website, but i got stucked at Selection.Insert

This is what i wanna get,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkPAD.png)

Thanks before :)

Comment: So you want to duplicate entries in columns A/B? Looks as if you have gaps in your data? Probably easier to put the results on a separate sheet or different columns.

Comment: its solved and u were right, thanks :)